# Terminal is not executing commands

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Yesterday I was tweaking with profile. After that don't know what happened since then no commands are executing. Whenever I try to execute a command it is showing me the profile page again and again. The following pictures are of the terminal's before  command and after command.

Before command execution

[image]

After command execution

[image]

Comment: I guess you've created a shortcut key. Open Edit -> Preferences -> Shortcuts and see if Profile Preferences has the Return key assigned. If so, double click on it and press Backspace to remove it.

Comment: According to the chosen tags, you are using Ubuntu 15.10, which has gone EOL and so you should upgrade to 16.04. However, I suspect your problem is not related to the version of Ubuntu used, so I have removed the 15.10 tag to prevent your question from being closed as off-topic for using an EOL version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Delete the `Unnamed` profile and see if that fixes your problem. If you play with profiles again, be careful about what you changed, and/or tell us about what changes you made so we can help more. Cheers, Al